# Is there any CI service that will pull from dockerhub?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, docker, travis-ci, dockerhub

I have investigated: Travis CI, Circle CI, Drone.io but they all seems to want to pull from github. However, I have dockerhub pull from github and build the docker image properly already.

I also looked at Jenkins, it seems to have a plugin that can pull from dockerhub, but I have not figured out how to use it yet. I'll continue that but the issue with Jenkins is that I have to host it myself.

I am looking for CI service that can pull from docker hub, run test on the image, show test results in web UI and also call back docker hub to let it know what happened so if test failed, dockerhub will not issue the webhook to push to production.

Anyone know anything like what I described? Thank you very much!

==Update==
I have been continuing researching all the CI options. I notice 2 trends:

1. Replace their old virtualization solution with Docker. For example Travis CI [here](http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/) . For example drone.io that uses Docker as the container to run test from the beginning as described [here](http://blog.drone.io/2014/2/5/open-source-ci-docker.html). However, I do not think they can run another layer of container inside of them anymore, you just run your tests. And I don't think you can build docker image either.
2. Make their old virtualization solution support Docker CLI and then you can build docker image, deploy the image to registry and even run test inside the docker container, for example [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/docker) .

2 IMHO is better than 1 for me. If 1&2 can be combine it would be cool. However, both solution starts with source code and want to do the 'build'. They do not have the ability to pull from DockerHub. And I'm not sure about how good the support is for testing inside the docker container. I'm still experimenting.

Comment: This question is off-topic in this site; I'd suggest to try on serverfault, and if you like, also add the question as a sample into this new site proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops

Comment: @guido I'm unconvinced this is appropriate for serverfault. Devops would seem to be appropriate, but it is still in definition and frankly doesn't look very active. It seems to be being asked by a developer, so I have to say that SO is currently the most appropriate site.

Comment: @guido , you have a point. But docker is really a game changer, it unifies the dev test and deployment environment. So as a developer who is now also in charge of writing test, deploy to production and oncall when things break, I do think the line is bluring.

Comment: @guido This is most certainly not appropriate for [sf]. If it wasn't blatantly a shopping question, it would be appropriate for [so].

Answer (score 3):

Given the answer by Nathaniel Waisbrot it seems that Jenkins is a valid choice to get what you are looking for, which is, basically, access to docker hub and bring up a container as part of your build and testing process.

In order get this working you will need a high level of customization (configuration at machine level) for your Jenkins instance. I think [ClinkerHQ](http://clinkerhq.com) could fit your needs, since it provides a dedicated hosted environment that can be highly customized (even installing additional tools to use in Jenkins Shell Script steps). You should take a look at the [Jenkins Docker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) if you want to provision Jenkins slaves dinamically with docker.

DISCALIMER: I'm deeply involved in ClinkerHQ.

Comment: Thank you @amuniz . Cloud hosting Jenkins may be my final solution for my current situation. This may be off the topic a little bit but in your opinion what is the ClinkerHQ advantage over things like https://bitnami.com/ and http://jenkinshosting.com/ (which I feel is more delicated to host Jenkins)?

Comment: @GordonSun bitnami will provide you with a Jenkins instance preconfigured and ready to use, but you are responsible of that instance just after creation, not so in ClinkerHQ. The other service (jenkinshosting) will allow you to configure the Jenkins instance, but I'm not sure if they will allow you to install things at low level (for example, having docker at CLI). Moreover, ClinkerHQ includes other services, like SonarQube which could be interesting if you want to get some code quality metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with Jenkins, using the "execute shell" command to run `docker pull`. It's easy to set up: just put Jenkins in the `docker` group.

If you use Fig (I haven't converted over to docker-compose to see if it's still a problem there) then you'll need to run things like

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4 -c 'import pty, sys; sys.exit(pty.spawn(sys.argv[1:]) != 0)' fig run my_container ./bin/test
```

because Fig needs a TTY to run.

You could set up a web-hook to trigger Jenkins from the Docker Hub, but I would probably just take the lazy path and either build periodically or trigger on the same Git change as the Hub but with a 30 minute delay.

---

**Edit**: I had looked for a hosted solution (like Travis) to do this, rather than running my own Jenkins, but didn't find anything. I think the main problem is that the CI providers make their profit by hosting many customers on one machine. But allowing someone to run arbitrary Docker containers is a major security problem.

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel ! I voted up your answer but I have not select it as the accepted answer yet. I will continue to play with Jenkins but I really want to not host anything myself. I hope someone know some Saas that I can just sign up and pay for it like Travis CI for pre-docker world.

Comment: Please add your own answer if you find something. I'd love to know about it. I looked for a hosted solution, too, and didn't have any luck but that was several months ago now.

Comment: I see your point about host company does not want to run docker on their machine. I'm not familiar with them, I don't know how they were able to do integration test before. They need to run the code to test the code right? How did they manage to avoid security risk before?

Comment: In Travis, you're inside a VM (that can't run Docker itself). In Drone, you're inside a Docker container (but can't spawn sibling containers). You need to be inside a VM that's full-featured enough to let you start containers (like an EC2 instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shippable to do this - www.shippable.com

Pull from Docker hub is supported, as is Dockerbuild. You can also enable the workflow of - pull image from docker hub ->pull code from github->test code inside container->if CI passes, push container to Docker Hub. 
http://blog.shippable.com/making-deployments-even-easier-with-docker-build

Answer (score 0):

Codeship has this feature in "public" beta testing (you can ask them to include you in the beta if you want to try it out), they said the feature going to be available at the end of summer.